# The number of states in DFA that accepts strings with length that is divisible by $3$ or $5$.

Tags: automata

I know that the answer is $15$ states, but I cannot get my mind to understand why is that? which property makes it impossible to do it in less states? I've tried to mess with it for a long time and still can't find the property that forces me to use $15$ states. 
This also seems true for all DFA's of these type, if it accepts strings of length $x$ or $y$, then the number of states it needs is $xy$. 
I would really appreciate it if someone could tell me the specific reason of why this happens?

Comment: Do you know how to prove that if you replace "$3$ or $5$" by $7$, you need $7$ states?

Comment: For the second part of your question, the answer is not $xy$, but $\text{lcm}(x,y)$.

Comment: @markvs I don't really know how to formally prove these things or how this proof looks like, but I can understand intuitively that we need to save the knowledge of when does the length become divisible by $7$, and for that we must have $7$ states

Comment: You may want to use syntactic monoids of these languages.

Comment: Look at such papers: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226652130_On_Deterministic_Finite_Automata_and_Syntactic_Monoid_Size

Comment: Indeed, look at Theorem 2 here: https://cse.buffalo.edu/~regan/cse681/notes/lectureA03.pdf

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Building a Deterministic Finite Automaton with the set {a}](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1107340/building-a-deterministic-finite-automaton-with-the-set-a)

Comment: @markvs The linked question is different since it is just asking for a DFA, but this one asks for the minimal DFA.